# Ubuntu one notices things are not in sync, but doesn't actually sync

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

Ubuntu one recognizes that some folders are not synced, but does not actually sync them.
It used to work, but at some point I noticed some folders not being in sync anymore.
No, I haven't reached my storage limits.

Starting the ubuntu one application results in a 'Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error' message.

What is going on, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu One will be shutting down in June.  You might as well move your files over to Dropbox or Onedrive now.
[Canonical to shutdown Ubuntu One](http://www.engadget.com/2014/04/03/ubuntu-one-shutdown/)

Comment: Well, thanks I guess. Indirectly solved the problem :)